# FirebaseError: Firebase: A network AuthError (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred. (auth/network-request-failed)

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase-authentication, firebase-tools

I'd like to set up my Angular app to use Firebase's emulators and followed [this guide](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/emulators/emulators.md) to set up my `app.module.ts` as follows:

```
import { USE_EMULATOR as USE_AUTH_EMULATOR } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import { USE_EMULATOR as USE_DATABASE_EMULATOR } from '@angular/fire/compat/database';
import { USE_EMULATOR as USE_FIRESTORE_EMULATOR } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';

@NgModule({
  // ... Existing configuration
  providers: [
    // ... Existing Providers
    { provide: USE_AUTH_EMULATOR, useValue: environment.useEmulators ? ['http://localhost', 9099] : undefined },
    { provide: USE_DATABASE_EMULATOR, useValue: environment.useEmulators ? ['http://localhost', 9000] : undefined },
    { provide: USE_FIRESTORE_EMULATOR, useValue: environment.useEmulators ? ['http://localhost', 8080] : undefined },
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

There are no errors after running `firebase emulators:start` as well as `ng serve`. If I try to log in, I get the following error in Chrome: `FirebaseError: Firebase: A network AuthError (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred. (auth/network-request-failed)`. There is also a failed network request: `POST http://localhost/identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=API_KEY net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

If I try the same action in FireFox, I get this error: `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost/identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=API_KEY. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed)` along with the ones I get in Chrome.

The guide I was following said to use `localhost` instead of `http://localhost` though when the page loaded, I got the error `FirebaseError: Firebase: Emulator URL must start with a valid scheme (http:// or https://). (auth/invalid-emulator-scheme)` in the DevTools console. I'm using `"@angular/fire": "^7.0.3"`

What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: It seems you got past the error mentioned in the title and you now have a CORS error. I suggest updating the title and question to reflect that.

Comment: @BizzyBob Thanks for the advice! I've updated the question to reflect the new problem.

Comment: You can run Chrome with the `--disable-web-security` flag as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3102819/1858357).  Here's I've been using on mac `open -n -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --args --user-data-dir="/tmp/chrome_dev_test" --disable-web-security`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by downgrading to `@angular/fire` v6